# Switching from a SpriteKit scene to a UIview in storyboard

Tags: uistoryboard, sprite-kit

Hello I am trying to make a simple game where the game is a sprite kit scene, but the menus and game over screens are in story board. How can I switch from a scene to a UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following method: (I to suppose you have a rootViewController so that you may present the view, and also that the Views you wish to present have an identifier in the Storyboard, so that you may instantiate them)

Example:

```
//The method which presents the view you wish to display:

-(void)presentUIView{
    UIViewController *myview = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyView"]; 
    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:myView animated:YES completion:nil];
}

//And then when you wish to dismiss the view to go back (called inside the View): 
-(void)dismissItself:(id)sender{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Worked when I changed MyViewController to UIViewController

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I meant, you can only present ViewControllers since UIView is the class from where all UI elements (like buttons, labels, images..) extend from and are managed by the ViewController I believe. Cheers!